# "Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly" in password authentication

Tags: python, django

When trying to `authenticate` I have the error.

```
password = request.POST['password'].encode('utf-8')
user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
```

Maybe the problem is in my `auth.` backend?
I convert password into md5 in `auth.` backend.

```
password = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
```

Comment: I'd bet it is your auth backend. How come you don't use Django's built-in password hashers?